# Implementing a TLS proxy using OpenSSL

Tags: c, ssl, proxy, openssl

I have a requirement to implement a TLS Proxy kind of application using OpenSSL. Here is brief details about what I am trying to accomplish.

My application is listening to TLS client connections. It does some processing to initial few requests from client and sends modified data to backend server over TLS. Similarly response received from backend server will be modified and then send it to client.

After few initial requests application goes in a pure proxy mode wherein it reads data received from client, write to backend connection and read data received from backend, write it to client connection.
I could implement it with OpenSSL and everything works well, except the last part of going into pure proxy mode. For that part what I did is, I created another pthread. Main thread reads data from client connection using SSL_read and writes into backend connection using SSL_write, second thread reads data from backend connection and writes into client connection. I am using blocking BIO in my application.

Here is my code sample for that:

```
typedef struct proxy_args_t {
    SSL* source;
    SSL* target;
} proxy_args_t;

int pure_proxy(SSL *source, SSL *target)
{
    pthread_t pthread;
    proxy_args_t proxy_args;
    proxy_args.source = source;
    proxy_args.target = target;

    if (pthread_create(&pthread, NULL, proxy_handler, &proxy_args) != 0)
    {
        // error
        return -1;
    }
    do_proxy(target, source);
    return 0;
}

void *proxy_handler(void *args)
{
    proxy_args_t *proxy_args = (proxy_args_t *)args;
    do_proxy(proxy_args->source, proxy_args->target);
    return NULL;
}

void do_proxy(SSL *source, SSL *target)
{
    char buf[BUF_LEN];
    ssize_t len;
    while ((len = SSL_read(source, buf, BUF_LEN)) > 0)
    {
        if (SSL_write(target, buf, len) > 0)
        {
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

My question is, what would be the best way to perform this, I am not liking this two thread approach and I believe there must be a better way to do this.

Also, in this two thread approach, I am having issues in handling connection close. If I do SSL_shutdown and SSL_free in any of the thread upon close notify, I see SIGSEGV intermittently. Thanks for any feedback on this!

Comment: It is unclear what problem the thread solves.  You have two sockets.  When you receive on either of them, you send to the other.  Why couldn't you do that in the main thread?

Comment: Hi @stark, I wanted to send the data received from either of the connection immediately to the other connection. I used a blocking BIO, so SSL_read gets blocked. In the meantime if any data received from other connection, I thought another thread can process that. Can this be done in single thread? If you can share some example it would be great.